# how to clone a checkbox, now on unchecking hide that clonedbox and uncheck the parent and on unchecking parent hide the clonedbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.is(':checked')) {
    self.closest('.label-wrap').clone().addClass("clone")
      .appendTo("header");
    self.closest('.label-wrap').find('label').addClass("is-checked");
  } else {
    $('header label[for="' + self.attr('id') + '"]').replaceWith('');
    self.closest('.wrap').find('.clone').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <header></header>
  </div>
  <form class="col-md-6">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="label-wrap">
        <label for="one">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input id="one" type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="label-wrap">
        <label for="two">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input id="two" type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="label-wrap">
        <label for="three">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input id="three" type="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

here what i want to achieve is on checking box1 it has to create a clone element (clonedcheckbox1) and on unchecking cloned checkbox(clonedcheckbox1) hide that checkbox and uncheck parent checkbox(checkbox1) 

   [.]checkbox1                     [.]clonedcheckbox1

      []checkbox2                   

[.]checkbox3        [.]clonedcheckbox3

Comment: What happens if you uncheck `checkbox1`? Does the clone get removed only?

Comment: yes only the respective cloned box is removed, now what i want is on unchecking cloned box hide that checkox and uncheck the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delegate a change event so that your binding can be done onready to remove the clone and uncheck the original when the clone is unchecked:

```js
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $parent = $this.parent();

  if (this.checked) {
    // if checked clone without events and append
    $parent.after($parent.clone().addClass('clone'));
  } else {
    // otherwise remove clone
    $parent.next('.clone').remove();
  }
});

$('.wrap').on('change', '.clone .checkbox', function() { // delegate your event for dynamically added elements
  // can only be unchecked
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest('.wrap').find('.checkbox').prop('checked', false); // use prop to uncheck original
  $this.parent().remove(); // remove clone
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <header></header>
  </div>
  <form class="col-md-6">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="label-wrap">
        <label for="one">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input id="one" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="label-wrap">
        <label for="two">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input id="two" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="label-wrap">
        <label for="three">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input id="three" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: instead of adding "after" how can we append to header section and achieve same functionality?

Comment: Hi Chetan, please ask a new question - link to this one if needed to add context.  But you could just use `.append()` instead of `.after()`